# Subscriptions/ In-app purchase - some new chnages?

Tags: iphone, ios5, in-app-purchase, subscriptions

Is there some new subscription mechanism requirement on iOS? So far we handled the subscriptions without involving Apple, but this (https://developer.apple.com/appstore/in-app-purchase/subscriptions.html) is saying something different:

> If you offer auto-renewable subscriptions, you can also use other
>   methods to acquire digital subscribers outside of your app. You can
>   sell digital subscriptions on your website or provide free access to
>   content for existing subscribers. In these cases there is no revenue
>   sharing since Apple was not involved in the transactions. Developers
>   keep 100% of the revenue. **If you would like to make a subscription
>   offer outside of the app, the same (or better) subscription price must
>   be offered inside the app for users who wish to subscribe from within
>   the app.** In addition, you may not provide links in your apps which
>   allow the customer to purchase content or subscriptions outside of the
>   app.

I understand the In-app purchase is mandatory for one-time payments, but so far we were not forced to offer subscriptions over In-app purchase mechanism...

BR
STeN

Answer (score 1):

My historical understanding as well as my understanding of that specific text is that, yes, they require you to offer the IAP subscription inside your app since you're offering it outside as well.  I think you've just gotten lucky so far that they haven't noticed.

Comment: Hi, the problem is that the application passed a QA 2 months ago and we openly explain them how the subscription model works. Even more - there are dozens of applications (including big brands) which use the subscription mechanism and none of them is using IAP. Anyway giving 30% to Apple kills a business